# Unable to change some js/html file content on container start. getting access denied exception

Tags: c#, docker, asp.net-core-3.1

I have a case where i need to inject some Envrionment variable values in compiled vuejs js/html file which resides inisde my .net core 3.1 application.
I have put the content changing logic on startup.cs in Configure method.
I am getting Access denied exception
My code is

```
private void ReplaceEnvironmentVariableWithVal()
        {
            try
            {
                string apiurlToken = "VUE_APP_BEAPI_URL";
                string relevantPath = "VUE_APP_RELEVANTPATH";
                string path = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location), "clientapp", "dist", "js");
                Console.WriteLine($"{apiurlToken} env value is {GetEnvVariable(apiurlToken)}");
                Console.WriteLine($"{relevantPath} env value is {GetEnvVariable(relevantPath)}");
                Console.WriteLine("Application Root Path of js files " + path);
                DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(path);
                Dictionary<string, string> dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
                if (dir != null)
                {
                    foreach (var file in dir.GetFiles())
                    {
                        if (file.Extension == "js" || file.Extension == ".js")
                        {
                            var fileContent = File.ReadAllText(file.FullName);
                            if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(fileContent))
                            {

                                if (fileContent.Contains(apiurlToken))
                                {
                                    string variableValue = GetEnvVariable(apiurlToken);
                                    if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(variableValue))
                                    {
                                        fileContent = fileContent.Replace(apiurlToken, variableValue);
                                        dict[file.FullName] = fileContent;
                                    }

                                }

                                if (fileContent.Contains(relevantPath))
                                {
                                    string variableValue = GetEnvVariable(relevantPath);
                                    //if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(variableValue))
                                    {
                                        fileContent = fileContent.Replace(relevantPath, variableValue);
                                        dict[file.FullName] = fileContent;
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Application Root Path of js files not exists");
                }
              
                foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> entry in dict)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Updating " + entry.Key);
                    using (var fs = new FileStream(entry.Key, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
                    {
                        using var sr = new StreamWriter(fs);
                        sr.Write(entry.Value);
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine("Update Completed " + entry.Key);
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Exception in ReplaceEnvironmentVariableWithVal:" + ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

Comment: I know this is not recommended approach. but let's say i am looking for anti pattern/workaround for something

Comment: Which user are you running your container as? What are the user/group/permissions on the file you are trying to change? Is it on a path mounted on a volume or bound to a host dir? Why don't you fix that at build time directly in your image? Can't your application read those values directly from environment variables (with possible default values if not set) which are easy to define at container launch time?

Comment: it is on host dir. We needed to upload the image once and used with different environment variable for some of our backend api url. In vuejs build creation we have some limitation to read from env as envrionmentvariables are part of dist creation.

Comment: i have no idea about which user. i think default user is running the application

Comment: Console.WriteLine("Current UserName " + Environment.UserName); resulted in default

Comment: `docker exec your_container id -a`. Check the uid/gid and compare that to the perms on file your are trying to change. You really need to edit your question to add more debugging details because it is impossible to help you here. Moreover, what you are trying to do is basically evil and you should really consider refactoring the way you build or run your image and how your application gets its configuration on start. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks Zeitounator. with your hint i have first checked the user under which my application is running. then I have added following line in my docker file which give user permission. then i am bale to change content of the files. COPY --chown=default:default . .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have achieve the writing of files my giving the user right's. i have log the user under which application was running and it was default.
then added following line in my docker file
COPY --chown=default:default . .

which basically given right's to the user